# Clojure pre and post build hooks

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel

I have a project.clj with the following

```
:aliases {
      "build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export"]
    }
:cljsbuild {
    :builds[{
      :id "dev"
      :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
      :figwheel {
      :css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
      :ring-handler :ring
      }
      :compiler {
             :main scripts.functions,
             :output-to "build/js/main.js",
             :output-dir "build/js/",
             :optimizations :none,
             :source-map true,
             :source-map-timestamp true,
             :recompile-dependents false
           }
```

the alias "build-site" exports html files and assets to a build directory

I would like to run the fig wheel scenario and would like to have the aliases run before fig wheel processes or included in the `lean figwheel` call.

How can I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

`["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export" ["cljsbuild" "auto"]]`

seems to include the `["cljsbuild"....` as arguments how can i escape that ?

also

`["build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export" ] [":cljsbuild" "auto"]]`

give me a

> Map literal must contain an even number of forms.

Yet in the sample. project.clj this seem to be an accepted syntax....how come?

Keep getting

> Wrong number of args (2) passed to quote {:form (quote cjohansen-no.web/export [])}

this is the export file....

`(defn export []
  (let [assets (optimizations/all (get-assets) {})]
    (stasis/empty-directory! export-dir)
    (optimus.export/save-assets assets export-dir)
    (stasis/export-pages (get-pages) export-dir {:optimus-assets assets})))`

this is the aliases

`"build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export []"]
        "build" ["cljsbuild" "auto"]`

this is the command

`lein build-site build`

Comment: I'm not sure if you would like to handle it that way, but you can alias [multiple](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L232) commands.

Comment: @kongeor what do you mean exactly? I'm new to the language so your advice appreciated

Comment: I tried the syntax ```["build" ["build-site" "figwheel"]]``` but kept throwing me argument error like 

> "Wrong number of args (1) passed to...export"

Comment: Try it with: `:aliases {
      "build-site" ["run" "-m" "cjohansen-no.web/export"]
      "build" ["do" ["build-site"] ["figwheel"]]`